# MySQL UPDATE based on 2 AJAX data parameters ($_POST)?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Trying an AJAX call that UPDATEs a row based on the ID (pid=38) and changes the value of a column to NULL based on the button value (taskimg0). I am able to make it work if I hardcode the value `$_POST['dtf']` to taskimg0, but with only one AJAX data parameter. How do I use both data parameters in the AJAX call and use the $_POST in the sql statement? I am new to both of these languages, sorry
**HTML**

```
 <input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="38">
<button class="remove-tf" name="submit" type="submit" value="taskimg0">Remove</button>
```

**AJAX**

```
      $(function() {
      $(".remove-tf").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/tf-delete.php',
          data: 'pid=' + $(".pid").attr("value") + '&dtf=' + $(".remove-tf").attr("value")
      });
      });
        });
```

**MySQL**

```
<?php
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();

$sql = "UPDATE tasks SET $_POST['dtf']=NULL WHERE pid=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['pid']);
if ($stmt->execute()){
    header('Location: /listings.php');
};
$stmt->close();
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

Comment: be careful though since column names cannot be bound, you should whitelist them instead, plus, you don't need a redirection as a response, just return a json string with a success true/ false key pair

Comment: `SET $_POST['dtf']=NULL` is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/) attacks. Since you can't parameterise this part of the query, you need to whitelist the column names, and validate the user input against the whitelist, before you allow it to become part of your SQL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$(this).val();
```

This gets the value attached to the clicked button

Also it's dangerous to pass table,column names from your form.

You can easily attach the value `pid` and `dtf` to the button instead

```
<button class="remove-tf" pid="38" name="submit" type="submit" value="taskimg0">Remove</button>
```

Then in your data param for ajax, do this

```
data: 'pid=' + $(this).attr("pid") + '&dtf=' + $(this).val()
```

But as @Kevin mentioned, whitelist the `dtf` value before throwing it into your query

```
$acceptedColNames = ['taskimg0'];

if(in_array((string)$_POST['dtf'], $acceptedColNames) === false){
    die('Attempt to change value');//stop processing
}
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` im not sure why this got upvoted, the OP's code will yield the same result. much better if you pointed out that OP should use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit`. the problem is the quoting on the query. but prepared statement won't help in this case since the input is a column name, it should be whitelisted instead

Comment: i cant attach the value to the button, because the input value depends on a click before this instance. I did it for simplicity, also the input is inside a form and needs to be submitted.